# Initializing a computed variable using an observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I am trying to filter an observable array and store the filtered array into a computed variable. I wrote a Typescript class constructor, code inside that is as follows:

```
var self = this;
self.Items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Items, function (item: IShipmentItem) {
        return new _refShipmentItem.Model.ShipmentItem(item);
    }));
self.FrtDetlRowItems = ko.computed(function () {
        var frtdetlRows = ko.observableArray<_refShipmentItem.Model.ShipmentItem>([]);
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Items(), function (item) {
            if (item.AccessorialId == '1' && item.Cost != '') {
                frtdetlRows.push(item);
            }
        });
        return frtdetlRows;
    });
```

But whenever I check this in Console "FrtDetlRowItems" gives me "undefined".
am I doing anything wrong?
Please help

Comment: I don't think `observableArray<_refShipmentItem.Model.ShipmentItem>` is valid syntax? Change it to `ko.observableArray();`

Comment: thanks RGraham, I did it now it is not "undefined". but still FrtDetlRowItems().length is zero but if I check the frtdetlRows().length its count is other than zero, ofcourse depends upon data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to return as follows :

```
return frtdetlRows();
```

from the computed function.